# Powershell - Run SCP command from CYGWIN but also expand variables

Tags: powershell, scp, cygwin

I need to expand variables before running the `SCP` command as a result I can't use single quote. If I run the script using double quotes in  `Powershell ISE` it works fine.

But doesn't work if I run the script through command prompt.

I'm using zabbix to run the script which calls the script as `[cmd /C "powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\myscript.ps1"]`

Here is the code that needs to run SCP using Cygwin bash.

```
if ((test-path  "$zipFile"))
{ 
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l "set -x; scp /cygdrive/e/logs/$foldername/dir1/$foldername.zip root@10.10.10.10:~/"
}
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/bash: set -x;  /cygdrive/e/logs/myfolder/dir1/server.zip root@10.10.10.10:~/: No such file or directory
```

If I run the same command above in Cygwin manually it works.

I even tried to use `bash -l -c` but then the SSH session is stuck maybe because the `root@10.10.10.10` becomes $1 according to the documentation.

[Documentation link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

```
   -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from
             the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are
             arguments after the command_string, the first argument is
             assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to
             the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the
             name of the shell, which is used in warning and error
             messages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was halting when using `bash -c` was due to `StrictHostKeyChecking`, the known hosts thing (where you get a prompt to type yes/no).  I set the `-v` switch to `SCP` and it showed me the Debug logs where it was halting.

Had to set `scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` options.

The complete line now looks like the following:

```
c:\$cygwin_folder\bin\bash.exe -c ("/usr/bin/scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -v -i /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa  /cygdrive/e/logs/$foldername/dir1/$foldername.zip root@10.10.10.10:~/")
```